# Inheritance with async/await initialization methods

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, async-await, static-methods

My class has properties that need to be initialized. As I don't want to pass through a partially constructed object, and constructors can't/shouldn't be made async, I have been using the Factory Pattern described [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html), so my class looks like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public PropType AsyncProp1 { get; set; }

    public static async Task<BaseClass> CreateObject()
    {
        var baseClass = new BaseClass()
        {
            AsyncProp1 = await GetProp1Async()
        };
        return baseClass;
    }
}
```

So far that pattern has served me well, but now I need to implement other classes that will extend BaseClass and will have other async properties that need to be initialized before their objects can be used.

My initial plan was to simply override the CreateObject() method, but static methods can't be made virtual/override. I have then decided to hide the CreateObject() method in the base class and have a new CreateObject() method in the derived class that looks like this:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public PropType AsyncProp2 { get; set; }

    public static new async Task<DerivedClass> CreateObject()
    {
        var derivedClass = new DerivedClass()
        {
            AsyncProp1 = await GetProp1Async(),
            AsyncProp2 = await GetProp2Async(AsyncProp1) // can't do that - AsyncProp1 is not static
        };
        return derivedClass;
    }
}
```

Needless to say that for every derived class I need to rewrite the initialization of the inherited properties. That alone goes against the whole inheritance concept, but the worst part is that some of these new async properties in the derived classes depend on the old async properties in the base class, but I can't simply call on them inside the CreateObject() method because they are not static properties.

Is there any way I can improve on what I have at the moment, work around this Catch22 issue, and achieve what was described above?

**[EDIT]**

Just to give a bit of context, the reason why I don't want to depend on initialization methods called outside my classes is that I may not have control over the code creating objects and calling such initialization methods. That is why I would rather return a "ready to use" object back to the caller.

Comment: How about having a single virtual async Init function that you call after the object is created?  (i.e. instead of a createobject function, just require the caller to call the async Init)

Comment: @Wyck Yes, I thought of doing that, but I would really like to avoid passing uninitialized objects around. I would rather have them ready for use after they are created, without having to call other methods. That's just a personal preference though, not a design constraint. I understand that given my actual constraints, that may not be possible, so I might revisit that option if I can't find a better pattern.

Comment: It's not that the object is "uninitialized".  It's just "unawaited"  It's fine to pass the Tasks into the constructors and not await them until the async Init is called.  Perhaps you could let go of the idea of awaiting the Task in the factory function.  e.g.: Store `Task<PropType>` and then when async Init is called, await the Task and store the result in the PropType variable.

Comment: @Wyck I believe what you are proposing is somewhat the "The Asynchronous Initialization Pattern" described [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). I could do that even without a Task<PropType> just by having **var newObject = new BaseClass();** followed by **await newObject.InitAsync();** in my caller. But I would rather avoid that as I explained before.

Comment: Just to give a bit of context, the reason why I would rather not depend on initialization methods called outside my classes is that I may not have control over the code creating objects of my classes and calling these initialization methods.

Comment: The initialization calls can be made inside of your classes, or are you worried that someone will create another derived class, create a new `CreateObject` and they won't implement it fully?

Comment: IMHO, protected constructor & virtual async init method. Let the derived class override init and choose when to call the base init method. But always call the init method from your factory method(s), so you don't need to worry about external uses. Then, if you don't need additional arguments, your factory could be `Task<T> CreateObject<T> .. where T:BaseClass,new()`

Comment: @JohanP No, I am okay with having initialization methods **inside** my classes (that is, called by other methods within them). That's not a problem because I will have control over the base class and any derived classes. The only thing I would like to avoid is any callers having to call the initialization methods after having created objects.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman But if my factory methods are to call the init methods, the init methods would have to be static (as the factory methods are static themselves), and therefore could not be virtual/override... Or am I missing something? The factory methods do have a couple of parameters, if that is what you meant. I omitted them in the question for simplicity.

Comment: I think you should read Stephen Cleary's [very next post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) stating that it's an oxymoron to have your asynchronously initialized object have an api that exposes a public non-asychronous property (`AsyncProp1`).  This amounts to wanting an async property.  You could redesign the interface to this object so that any of its methods are also async and just let those methods internally ensure that it is initialized (awaiting InitAsync if necessary).  ...If preventing misuse is your primary goal.

Comment: You could create a private ctor for your derived class that takes in a baseclass. In there you set your base class props. So you can do something like this `private DerivedClass(BaseClass bc)
 {
  AsyncProp1 = bc.AsyncProp1;
 }

    public static new async Task<DerivedClass> CreateObject()
    {
     var bc = await BaseClass.CreateObject();
        var derivedClass = new DerivedClass(bc)
        {
            AsyncProp2 = await GetProp2Async(bc.AsyncProp1)
        };
        return derivedClass;
    }`

Comment: @Wyck Thanks, that post really helped! My case I believe would fit exactly the "Cached Values" scenario, as I only need to evaluate the async operation once when retrieving the properties for the first time. So, going with AsyncLazy<T> would probably be my best bet. Would you like to go ahead and post that as an answer, so that I can accept it as a solution and grant you the due reputation points?

Comment: @JohanP That would probably work just fine as well. Thanks for that! The AsyncLazy<T> solution proposed by Wyck is easier/better in the sense I wouldn't even need the Factory Pattern or initialization methods any longer. If that doesn't work, I will default to your solution. Cheers!

Comment: Just a side note: I tend to prefer a separate Factory type (as opposed to a static `CreateAsync`). But each case is different; sometimes `AsyncLazy<T>` is exactly what you want (the disadvantage is that every property read then needs an `await`). When I wrote those blog posts, I was hoping that DI containers would adopt an async creation pattern of some kind. However, that does not look like it's ever going to happen.

Comment: @StephenCleary First off, thanks for those articles. I'm new to async programming, and they have been helping me a lot. After reading your comment I went back to check on them and just realized you wrote them over 8 years ago! It is impressive how they remain helpful and up-to-date after all this time, especially in a field like ours. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read Stephen Cleary's [very next post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) stating that it's an oxymoron to have your asynchronously initialized object have an API that exposes a public non-asychronous property (`AsyncProp1`). This amounts to wanting an *async* property.

You could redesign the interface to this object so that any of its methods are also *async* and just let those methods internally ensure that it is initialized (awaiting `InitAsync` if necessary). ...if preventing misuse is your primary goal.